# not using input after first pass of loop

Tags: c++, loops, do-while

The intent is to ask a user if they want to play, output options, receive userinput and then simulate a 'roll' the appropriately sided dice.  Output the results, and then ask for another choice, etc.

The first cycle of the program works as it should, but instead of it asking if you want to play again it is blank.  If you enter a number to select the dice it will output how many sides the first dice had no matter what is chosen.

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <ctime>        
using namespace std;


int throwDie(int Sides, int &throwResult)
{
throwResult = 1 + rand() % (Sides - 1 + 1); 
return throwResult;                      
}
int main()
{           
int dieTot = 0,
        throwNumber = 0,
    numberSides = 0,
    throwResult = 0;
    int die1 = 4;
    int die2 = 6;
    int die3 = 8;
    int die4 = 10;
    int die5 = 12;
    int die6 = 20;

    char rollAgain;
    srand(unsigned(time(0) ));
    START:   
    cout << "Do you want Play? ";
    cin >> rollAgain;

    cout << "How many sides? " << endl;
    cout << "1 - 4 sided die\n";
    cout << "2 - 6 sided die\n";
    cout << "3 - 8 sided die\n";
    cout << "4 - 10 sided die\n";
    cout << "5 - 12 sided die\n";
    cout << "6 - 20 sided die\n";

    int choice;
    cout << "Enter choice: ";
    cin >> choice;

    switch( choice ) {
        case 1:
            do {
                cout << "You have choosen a 4 sided die? " << endl;
                int numberSides = die1;
                cout << numberSides << "-sided die rolled for a value of "
                     << throwDie(numberSides, throwResult) << "!" << endl;
                dieTot = dieTot + throwResult;
                throwNumber++;
                cin >> numberSides;
            } while (choice != numberSides );
            goto START;
            break;

        case 2:
            do {
                cout << "You have choosen a 6 sided die? " << endl;
                int numberSides = die2;
                cout << numberSides << "-sided die rolled for a value of "
                     << throwDie(numberSides, throwResult) << "!" << endl;
                dieTot = dieTot + throwResult;
                throwNumber++;
                cin >> numberSides;
                cout << endl << "Total for " << throwNumber <<  " throws = " << dieTot << endl;
            } while (choice != numberSides );
            break;

        case 3:
            do {
                cout << "You have choosen a 8 sided die? " << endl;
                int numberSides = die3;
                cout << numberSides << "-sided die rolled for a value of "
                     << throwDie(numberSides, throwResult) << "!" << endl;
                dieTot = dieTot + throwResult;
                throwNumber++;
                cin >> numberSides;
                cout << endl << "Total for " << throwNumber <<  " throws = " << dieTot << endl;
            } while (choice != numberSides );
            break;

        case 4:
            do {
                cout << "You have choosen a 10 sided die? " << endl;
                int numberSides = die4;
                cout << numberSides << "-sided die rolled for a value of "
                     << throwDie(numberSides, throwResult) << "!" << endl;
                dieTot = dieTot + throwResult;
                throwNumber++;
                cin >> numberSides;
                cout << endl << "Total for " << throwNumber <<  " throws = " << dieTot << endl;
            } while (choice != numberSides );
            break;

        case 5:
            do {
                cout << "You have choosen a 12 sided die? " << endl;
                int numberSides = die5;
                cout << numberSides << "-sided die rolled for a value of "
                     << throwDie(numberSides, throwResult) << "!" << endl;
                dieTot = dieTot + throwResult;
                throwNumber++;
                cin >> numberSides;
                cout << endl << "Total for " << throwNumber <<  " throws = " << dieTot << endl;
            } while (choice != numberSides );
            break;

        case 6:
            do {
                cout << "You have choosen a 20 sided die? " << endl;
                int numberSides = die6;
                cout << numberSides << "-sided die rolled for a value of "
                     << throwDie(numberSides, throwResult) << "!" << endl;
                dieTot = dieTot + throwResult;
                throwNumber++;
                cin >> numberSides;
                cout << endl << "Total for " << throwNumber <<  " throws = " << dieTot << endl;
            } while (choice != numberSides );
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Not a proper entry.\n";
            break;

        cout << endl << "Total for " << throwNumber <<  " throws = " << dieTot << endl;

        return 0;
    }
}
```

I am assuming the extra code in each of the case statments is:

```
    cout << numberSides << "-sided die rolled for a value of " << throwDie(numberSides,                              throwResult) << "!" << endl;
    dieTot = dieTot + throwResult;
    throwNumber++;
    cin >> numberSides;
    cout << endl << "Total for " << throwNumber <<  " throws = " << dieTot << endl;
    }
while (choice != numberSides );
    break;
```

Would that go at the end of the code? Not in every case statement. Also if I do that would I even need to put the while/do into functions?

Comment: Hint: All that duplicated code in your `switch` statement is a sign you have some design problems.

Comment: put those `while/do` into functions....

Comment: he's misssing closing '}' as well for his switch..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing do with looping.

1. Try printout out the values obtained from your cin's and you'll see the problem.
2. You use your goto statement inconsistently, you only return to `START` in your first case
3. You don't properly terminate your switch statement
4. You should just about never use a goto unless you can't do it any other way.
5. This is horribly written.  Why do you need to duplicate everything in each case statement? Seems like you only need to use the switch for setting the value of numberSides and the print out.. The rest should be common... I don't think you need the variables either... see my raw refactor just of your code to simply things...

Refactoring your code makes it much more readable: see below

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <ctime>        
using namespace std;

//This function will throw a dice returning the result while updating the parameter.
int throwDie(int Sides, int &throwResult)
{
    throwResult = 1 + rand() % (Sides); //Sides - 1 + 1 == Sides
    return throwResult;                      
}

//Display the menu
void displayMenu()
{
    cout << "How many sides? \n"
         << "1 - 4 sided die\n"
         << "2 - 6 sided die\n"
         << "3 - 8 sided die\n"
         << "4 - 10 sided die\n"
         << "5 - 12 sided die\n"
         << "6 - 20 sided die\n"
         << "CTRL-D to quit";
}


int main()
{           
    int dieTot = 0,
        throwNumber = 0,
        numberSides = 0,
        throwResult = 0;
    // THESE ARENT NEEDED
    // sides = 4+2*(X-1)
    //int die1 = 4;
    //int die2 = 6;
    //int die3 = 8;
    //int die4 = 10;
    //int die5 = 12;
    //int die6 = 20;

    srand(unsigned(time(0) ));

    displayMenu();

    int choice;

    while ( cin >> choice ) {
        /* cin >> choice will return 0 / fail if they enter CTRL-D or enter
           something other than a number... you'll have to handle that in another way */

        if ( choice < 1 || choice > 6 ) {
            cout << "Invalid choice try again!";
            continue;
        }

        //numberSides = 4+2*(choice-1); //fast  way

        switch (choice) {
            case 6:
                numberSides = 20;
                break;
            case 1:
                //if you dont want to do this slick trick of fall through
                //numberSides = 4;
                //break; 
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
                numberSides = 4+2*(choice-1); // use this for 1,2,3,4,5;
                break;
        }

        cout << "You have chosen a " << numberSides << " sided die.\n"
             << numberSides << "-sided die rolled for a value of "
             << throwDie(numberSides, throwResult) << "!" << endl;
        dieTot += throwResult;
        throwNumber++;
    }

    cout << "\n\n" << "Total for " << throwNumber << " throws = " << dieTot << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I did a goto in all of the cases but same result. What am I doing wrong with terminating the switch statement, I followed a few I seen on the internet. What would be better to use than the goto? If I do not put all the info(other than you mentioned would I just put it once in the code? Where is your raw refactor located I do not see it. Sorry im asking a lot but I have been at this all day and im so lost. Thank you for the help tho.

Comment: @UpAndAdam You might also want to point out what happens if the user inputs something that isn't even a number when prompted for a choice. As is, I think your program would infinite-loop.

Comment: @DennisMeng It's not an infitnite loop. CTRL-D or something that's not a number will cause cin >> choice to fail and return false. Ironic that the very question you ask is what prevents said infinite loop.

Comment: Dam that was awesome but im learning the switch statements how would I incorporate that into this code

Comment: @UpAndAdam Wait, yes, you're right. Still might be useful to state for poster's benefit how it handles that though.

Comment: @user2770643  I had removed the ask yes or no thing at the moment to get you this far.  Putting that back in is straight forward now. Wanted to leave that for you..  Also as you can see in my explanation if they enter something that isn't a number it will exit the game currently.  you could get around this with something more complicated but I thought this was a good start for you. Trying to leave some stuff for you to learn by learning.

Comment: @user2770643 If you absolutely need to use a `switch` statement, you could use it to instantiate `numberSides` and then do all of the other logic. It looks like most everything else is duplicated

Comment: Our comments just did :-) but I'll add it to the post

Comment: @user2770643 I'll put a switch back in if you want to see one used 'user'

Comment: Actually there is a bug because of the 20 so I will use a switch!

Comment: Yes please put a switch in. Also I tried to rate but said i need a rep of 15 or more to vote

Comment: Thank you guys for the help! I also found out how to  format my code for future problems. Thanks for putting up with the lousy formatting.